# Unable to understand what kind of pdf and its origin

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

I am facing difficulty in identifying how the formula given by Eq(2) in the paper

> Wen-Chi Tsai and Anirban DasGupta, On the Strong Consistency, Weak Limits and Practical Performance of the ML Estimate and Bayesian Estimates of a Symmetric Domain in $R^k$, Lecture Notes-Monograph Series Vol. 45, A Festschrift for Herman Rubin (2004), pp. 291-308
>
> [download link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4356317?seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents)

expressed as the log-likelihood $$L(p,r|x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{\lambda{(B_{p,r})}^n} \mathbf{1}_{(p,r):x_i \in B_{p,r}} \forall i =1,2,\ldots,n$$

comes. 
In the expression $\lambda(B)$ is the Lebesgue measure of a ball $B_{p,r}$. $B_{p,r}$ denotes the centered $L_p$ ball with radius $r$ w.r.t the metric induced from $p$- norms in the $k$ -dimensional Euclidean space, $R^k$. 
In general, the log-likelihood expression is expressed as the logarithm of the pdf. Here, where is the pdf and why the Lebesgue measure goes in the denominator and what is the numeral one ?

I checked the references given below the formula [Table of Integrals Series and Products](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~ib38/tmp/reading/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2.pdf) pg 647 but could not find anything related to the pdf or the formula. Can somebody please explain what is the meaning of the expression and what is the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper states directly before equation $2$ that $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ are uniformly drawn from the set $S$.  The set $S$ was previously defined to be $B_{p, r}$, the $L^p$ ball of radius $r$ you mentioned above.  The density of such as uniform random variable can be stated as:
$$P(x_1, \cdots, x_n | p, r) = \frac{1}{\lambda(B_{p, r})}1_{(x_i \in B_{p,r}\,\forall i)}$$
Here $1_{(x_i \in B_{p,r}\,\forall i)}$ is the indicator function of the set $\{(x_i \in B_{p,r}\,\forall i)\}$.  That is the set of all $n$ tuples of $x_i$ that all live within the ball $B_{p,r}$.  The function is $1$ if all of the points are in the ball and $0$ otherwise.  The volume of the ball is in the denominator to normalize the uniform density and ensure the total probability is $1$.

Now the likelihood function is just the same formula with the understand that $\{x_i\}$ have been observed and is a function of $p, r$.

$$L(p, r | x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \frac{1}{\lambda(B_{p, r})}1_{(x_i \in B_{p,r}\,\forall i)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Uniform density is of the form $\frac{1}{b-a}$, where $a,b$ are estimated if unknown using estimators like Maximum likelihood etc. So, in this case is the Uniform density $\frac{1}{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the unknown volume that is estimated from the estimates of the parameters of the ball $p,r$? Why to use such fancy representation of the pdf and not just directly saying that it is uniform pdf? Lastly, what are these observations if the Authors are estimating the volume? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @SrishtiM  I'm not really familiar with the paper, I'm just answering your original question of which pdf produced the Likelihood function and what the symbols in it mean.

Comment: Absolutely agree and I did not expect you to go through the paper, sorry about that. Last Question, if you can further say why Uniform distribution is represented in this format and not just the usual way and what are the parameters of this distribution?

Comment: @ShristiM  The parameters of the distribution are $r$ and $p$ in the sense that it is the uniform distribution over the $L^p$ ball of radius $r$.  I can only speculate why they chose to represent it that way.  Agreed that it is not the simplest way to display a uniform distribution.  Perhaps it was does that way so that when they form the likelihood function, at least you see the parameter $p, r$ in the original density.  Then it is easier to conceive of how it becomes a function of them.